# Why enthalpy changes in phase transition when there is no change of temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

Why there is a change in enthalpy in phase transition?

I'm asking because enthalpy depends only on temperature:

$$\mathrm dH = C_p\,\mathrm dT,$$

and the change in temperature is $\mathrm dT = 0.$

Comment: It depends on n, P, V. too. dH = Q isn't general as in your statement. Your book or notes should have all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single phase, enthalpy is a function of temperature and pressure, and, at constant pressure, $\mathrm dH = C_p\,\mathrm dT.$

However, at a change of phase, enthalpy (per unit mass) undergoes a jump change, even at constant temperature and pressure.  If the phase change is from liquid to vapor, for example, this jump change in enthalpy is called the heat of vaporization.